# Shortening a directory with JavaFX media

Tags: java, javafx, media

I'm currently trying to get music to play out of a local directory. We managed to make it work with this declaration:

```
    public static String screen1music = "file:///C:/Users/Xenorosth%20XMD/Downloads/Direct-Parallax.mp3";
```

(I know, bad placement.)

However, I want to be able to shorten it so I can simply do "Direct-Parallex.mp3" What's  is the solution to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please you can use this

```
Media media= new Media(getClass().getResource("Direct-Parallex.mp3").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Thanks. Super fast answer!

Comment: This will not read from a Downloads directory, unless that Downloads directory is in the classpath and the current class belongs to the null package.